# How to generate WordPress plugin "update now" url?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How to generate the "update now" URL shown in the image?

[image: Update Now]

Answer (score 0):

This means there is a new version update available.

Here's [How to Submitting, and Maintaining Plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/planning-your-plugin)!

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Here is what I've done and the `$url` is the link I wanted:

```
$url = self_admin_url('update.php?action=upgrade-plugin&plugin=') . $plugin_name;
$url = wp_nonce_url($url, 'upgrade-plugin_' . $plugin_name);
```